# Using jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i'm starting to use modal dialog; i create this code reading, and with the help of few people

```
$('Form').submit(function(e) {
                    var url = "controllers/EntradaPedidos";
                    var dialog = $("#dialog");
                    if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
                        dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"> Los datos ingresados son:</div>').appendTo('body');
                    }
                    dialog.load(
                    url,
                    {}, // omit this param object to issue a GET request instead a POST request, otherwise you may provide post parameters within the object
                    function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                        dialog.dialog({
                            close: function(event, ui) {
                                dialog.remove();
                            },
                            modal: true,
                            buttons: {
                                Si: function() {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                    //EntradaPedidosProducto('Form');
                                },
                                No: function() {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            },
                            width: 460,
                            resizable: true
                        });
                    }
                );
                    return false;
                });



  <div id="dialog" title="Datos Cliente:" style="display: none;">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
        Estos son los datos que ingreso:
    </p>
    <p>
        Desea Continuar?
    </p>
```

so this are my doubts/questions

what i'm doing here

```
 var url = "controllers/EntradaPedidos";
```

i want to change window if the user push yes(si)

```
Si: function() {
     $(this).dialog("close");
     //EntradaPedidosProducto('Form');
},
```

how i do that

And finally, how can i push the data of the form on the modal dialog

Comment: what do you mean you want to continue the execution of your program?

Comment: change to the next window, and take the values of this window(form values) and use it in the next window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var url = "controllers/EntradaPedidos";
```

Setting the url to your ActionMethof called "EntradaPedidos" in a controller named "controllers" to a javascript variable called "url". This url will be used in the dialog.load method. (the dialog will load the content received from executing this action method)

If you want to save the value, do it here

```
 Si: function() {
                    //Read data and Save to DB using an ajax call
                },
```

Comment: i need the data of both windows(forms) before i can save on the database

Comment: You should be able to access it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
Si : function(){
  $(this).dialog("close");
   window.location = "/"+url;
}
```

Comment: what happens with the values of the form? i can use it in the next window?